# Page Not Found in Docusaurus

Tags: docusaurus

I'm trying to add add a new page in Docusaurus v2, so I added a new item in the `navbar`:

```
module.exports = {
  ...

  themeConfig: {
    navbar: {
      title: 'My Site: API Documentation',
      logo: {
        alt: 'My Site Logo',
        src: 'img/logo.png',
      },
      items: [
        {
          to: 'docs/',
          activeBasePath: 'docs',
          label: 'Docs',
          position: 'left',
        },
        {
          to: 'references/',
          activeBasePath: 'references',
          label: 'References',
          position: 'left',
        },
      ],
    },

    ...
  },
  presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        docs: {
          sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebars.js'),
          // Please change this to your repo.
          editUrl:
            'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/edit/master/website/',
        },
        theme: {
          customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Problem is that when I click the References link, I am redirected to http://localhost:3000/references/ which gives me a *Page Not Found* page:

[image]

Does anybody know where exactly I need to put my `*.md`s or what I should do to be able add a page inside `/references` and to access e.g. http://localhost:3000/references/dymmy_page?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options, things to check out. The first page you want showing up for /references, you can add the following to the frontmatter of that markdown file: `slug: /`

Or you can change to use docId (which I love). It's easier for using an ID and not remembering what file has a slug added to the frontmatter. The docid is the id from your markdown file, formatted just like the id in your sidebars.js (folder/id).

For example:

```
{
  type: 'doc',
  docId: 'folder-if-any/id-of-markdown-file',
  label: 'References',
  position: 'left',
},
```

If you add references in a dropdown menu, then it would be something like:

```
{
          label: 'Docs',
          position: 'left',
          items: [
            {
              type: 'doc',
              to: 'docs/folder-if-any/id-of-markdown-file',
              label: 'References',
            },
            {
              type: 'doc',
              to: 'docs/some-other-folder/id-of-markdown-file',
              label: 'Guide',
            },
          ]
        },
```